# VB6 crashing if Crystal Report is added

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have installed VB6 and Crystal Report 8.5. If I go to project and add Crystal Report 8.5, VB6 crashes. Here are the screenshots.

[image: Here I am clicking on the Project from Menu Bar]

[image: Adding Crystal Report 8.5]

[image: The crash screen]

Comment: Do you get an error message if you select debug program?

Comment: Let me try doing that again. I don't remember getting any though.

Comment: Unhandled exception in VB6.EXE: 0xC0000005: Access Violation

Comment: Is it trying to connect to a database for the reports. Check that you have access to the db etc

Comment: I do. The project is working fine with the database. Just this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Root Directory where VB6 id installed, select properties, and in compatibility tab select "Run this program in compatibility mode (Windows XP)" and "Run this program as an administrator"

Answer (score 0):

I had been facing the same issue since long, and due to this i was not able to upgrade my laptop to Win7 or 8, finally i resolved the issue, just go to the Root Directory where VB6 id installed, select properties, and in compatibility tab select "Run this program in compatibility mode (Windows XP)" and "Run this program as an administrator" Best of Luck

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Create a 0-byte file in the `C:\Windows` directory called `msjava.dll`.
- Change the compatibility settings for Visual Basic (to get it to run a little more smoothly under Windows 7) by browsing to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98`, right-clicking the `VB6.exe` file, and selecting properties.
- On the `Compatibility` tab, check the following:
- 1. `[Run V6.0 In Window 7]`
     Run this program in compatibility mode for Windows XP (Service Pack 3)
  2. Disable Visual Themes
  3. Disable Desktop Composition
  4. Disable display scaling on high DPI settings